# Jmeter - How to get HTTP Method as column in JTL file

Tags: jmeter

I have an endpoint that supports both post/get method.

I am looking for a JTL report that captures elapsed time like this

| URL | Method | Elapsed Time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| edituser.aspx | Get | 1200 |
| edituser.aspx | Post | 2500 |

Request help on resolving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default JMeter doesn't expose/store information about the [HTTP Request Method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) of the HTTP Request sampler

If you want to add it to the .jtl results file you can use the following steps:

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) to your Test Plan
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   vars.put('Method', prev.getHTTPMethod())
   ```
3. Add the next line to *user.properties* file:

   ```
   sample_variables=Method
   ```

That's it, next time you will run your test in command-line non-GUI mode the .jtl file will have an extra column with the HTTP Method for this particular sample result.

More information:

- [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy)
- [Sample Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html#sample_variables)

Comment: This does not give me the desired result when I have a redirection. 

 If edituser.aspx (POST request)  redirects the page to userdetails.aspx , the call prev.getHTTPMethod() returns "GET" .   I was expecting child  call in JTL (with 302 reponse code) for  edituser.aspx to have POST as method.   what to do this situation ?  @Dmitri-T